# Python Quantlib Incorrectly Bond Pricing Issue

Tags: python, quantlib

I was trying to use Python Quantlib to calculate Z-spread of a fixed coupon bond.

I used scipy to optimize the difference between spread-adjusted-bond-price and spread-free-bond-price to solve the spread. So I built a function using Quantlib to do the bond pricing, where in some specific cases, the bond price is calculated to be zero.

Here are my codes:

```
import QuantLib as ql

# bond info and settings
settlementDays = 0
settlementDate = ql.Date('2023-02-18', '%Y-%m-%d')
effectiveDate = ql.Date('2019-08-21', '%Y-%m-%d')
terminationDate = ql.Date('2023-02-21', '%Y-%m-%d')
faceAmount = 100
coupon = 0.0625
frequency = ql.Period(2)
paymentConvention = ql.Thirty360(ql.Thirty360.ISMA)
calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE)

# schedule
schedule = ql.Schedule(
    effectiveDate,
    terminationDate,
    frequency,
    calendar,
    ql.Unadjusted,
    ql.Unadjusted,
    ql.DateGeneration.Backward,
    False
)

# pricing curce

key_term_tenor = [0, 1, 3, 6, 12, 24, 36, 60, 84, 120, 240, 360, 1200]      # month
key_term_interest = [0, 0.049206, 0.049206, 0.050475, 0.050166, 0.046579, 0.043151, 0.040502, 0.039244, 0.038166, 0.040554, 0.038661, 0.038661]
key_term_spread = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

spot_dates = [settlementDate + ql.Period(round(tenor), ql.Months) for tenor in key_term_tenor]
spot_rates = [x + y for x, y in zip(key_term_interest, key_term_spread)]

spot_curve = ql.ZeroCurve(
    spot_dates,
    spot_rates,
    paymentConvention,
    calendar,
    ql.Linear(),
    ql.Compounded,
    ql.Annual
)

# bond
pricing_curve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(spot_curve)

bond = ql.FixedRateBond(
    settlementDays,
    faceAmount,
    schedule,
    [coupon],
    paymentConvention
)

bond.setPricingEngine(ql.DiscountingBondEngine(pricing_curve))

print(bond.cleanPrice())   # 0.0
print(bond.dirtyPrice())   # 0.0
```

Through the above codes, I got zero cleanprice and zero dirtyprice, got me confused. Is there something wrong in my codes?

An interesting finding is that bond.settlementDays is 2, which is not the same as what I input.

BTW, is there any better alternative solutions to solve the Z-spread?

Thanks!

I think the price should not be 0 obviously, something must be wrong here.

Comment: What confused me the most was the price of most "settlementDate"s, for example "2023-02-01", could be calculated correctly (at least not zero). But date "2023-02-18" or dates after would fail. The bond is not yet matured on "2023-02-18", so it should have a price.

Comment: Not related to your question but `spot_rates = [x + y for x, y in zip(...)]` is inefficient. Convert your lists to numpy arrays then `spot_rates = key_term_interest + key_term_spread`.

Answer (score 0):

To see what's happening, you can add

```
print(bond.settlementDays())
print(ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate)
print(bond.settlementDate())
```

at the end of your script.

Before doing that, though: are you setting the evaluation date?  Because that is missing from the code in your question, and without setting it the bond will be repriced as of today and it will be expired.  So, assuming that you also have added

```
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ql.Date(18,2,2023)
```

your code still returns price = 0, and the `print` statements above output

```
0
February 18th, 2023
February 21st, 2023
```

i.e., 0 settlement days, the evaluation date we just set, and the calculated settlement date.  (By the way, I'm using 1.32, but I see 0 settlement days even if I reinstall 1.28.  Are you sure you're getting 2?)

Why the bond settlement date is on February 21st, which causes the price to be 0 because we're at maturity and not trading anymore?  Because February 18th is a Saturday, the 19th is a Sunday, and the 20th (the third Monday in February) is President's day in the U.S. and therefore a bank holiday for the calendar you're using.  The first available trading day is the 21st, but that's too late.

If you try February 17th instead and set the evaluation date (and the curve nodes) accordingly, you're going to get a non-null price.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks! May I ask a little further, as I am confused by the redundant inputs “valuation date” vs “settlement date”. They looks being conflict in our example. what I want is to calculate the price on “valuation date”(Feb 18), when the bond on that day haven’t matured. (Although that day is not working day, what we are doing is just pricing, not settling bond, right?) . From the zero price output we know that Quantlib actually calculates the bond price on “settlement date”(Feb 21) when the bond was matured.  This is quite confusing. What does “settlement date” mean here?

Comment: Bond usually have a non-null number of settlement days.  Let's say a bond has 3 settlement days; this means that if you agree today to buy that bond from me, you'll actually get it after 3 days; in fact, if any cashflow occurs between today and the settlement day, I'll be the one that gets that cashflow, not you.  So, today is the valuation date, because we calculate the bond price as of today based on the market information we have; and the settlement date is when you actually get the bond.

Comment: The settlement date has a definite effect on pricing: only cashflows after the settlement date are considered, and they are discounted to the settlement date, not to today's date.